# breadcrumb not getting aligned center on changing the screen orientation

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've a set of icons at the top of the page. I want them to always aligned center. But when I change the orientation of the phone, icons get aligned to the left.
[Link to my page](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/ot/purchase_01.html)

```
<div id="breadcrumb"  data-theme="w">
            <div id="icon_01" class="icon" data-role="button"  data-theme="w" data-icon="smiley" data-iconpos="top">Personalize</div>
            <div class="arrow-icon" data-role="button"data-iconpos="top"  data-theme="w">»</div>
            <div id="icon_02" class="icon" data-role="button"  data-theme="w" data-icon="gift" data-iconpos="top">Gift Preview</div>
            <div class="arrow-icon" data-role="button"data-iconpos="top"  data-theme="w">»</div>
            <div id="icon_03" class="icon" data-role="button"  data-theme="w" data-icon="card" data-iconpos="top">Pay & Send</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#breadcrumb{
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    height: 35px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 480px;
}

#breadcrumb .ui-icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 21px;
}

#breadcrumb .ui-shadow{
    box-shadow: none;
}

.icon, .arrow-icon{float: left;}

.icon{
    min-width: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 75px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 12px;
}

#breadcrumb #icon_01.ui-btn-icon-top .ui-btn-inner{color: #666;}

#breadcrumb .ui-btn-icon-top .ui-icon {
    top: 0!important;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -12px!important;
}

#breadcrumb .ui-btn-icon-top .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 23px!important;
    margin-left: -10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block!important;
}

#breadcrumb .arrow-icon.ui-btn-icon-top .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 19px 0 0!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 36px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #ccc;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your page on my iPad.

You have a problem with #breadcrumb width. You have used this css:

```
margin: 10px auto 0;
```

You have horizontally centered #breadcrumb div which is good but your div size is 50% bigger then sum of inside images width. That is the reason why the div is not fully centered after page orientation event.

Change your #breadcrumb css to this:

## breadcrumb{

```
float: none;
clear: both;
margin: 10px auto 0;
height: 35px;
min-width: 280px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 280px;
```

}

EDIT:

You will need to play with width, I have a little different results on my iPad.